# SQL Server - Incorrect hour at GETDATE function (TimeZone)

Tags: sql-server, linux, timezone

I have a SQL Server server running on AWS, since yesterday the `GETDATE()` function has been returning the hour with one more hour as if it were in time zone `-02:00`. I have already checked on Linux and the date and time is correct and the time zone is set to `America/Sao_Paulo`.

Executing the following command `EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation', 'TimeZoneKeyName'` returns `E. South America Standard Time`, which in table `sys.time_zone_info` is with following values:

```
+-----------------------------+
| CURRENT_UTC_OFFSET | -02:00 |
| IS_CURRENTLY_DST   | 1      |
+-----------------------------+
```

How can I correct this time difference?

Comment: Could it be daylight savings settings are not as expected?

Comment: You say *"as if it were in time zone `-02:00`"* but then the data you show us shows that it *is* in `-02:00`, so i'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps SQL Server hasn't been updated for [Brazil Won't Change Clocks in 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-scraps-dst.html)?

Comment: The problem is that it *should* return `-03:00` at this time.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, exactly, Brazil this year will not have -02:00 timezone

Answer (score 0):

As Larnu mentioned, it would appear that the OS hosting your SQL Server has not been updated for [Brazil's end to DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-scraps-dst.html).

For Linux, ensure that the `tzdata` package is current.  (This change was made in [IANA TZDB 2019b](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2019-July/000056.html).)

For Windows, ensure that the updates mentioned in [this article from Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Daylight-Saving-Time-Time-Zone/Time-zone-updates-for-Brazil-are-available/ba-p/751175) have been applied.

Comment: The linux is up to date, and the hour at server is ok, but in SQL Server not

Comment: Just to clarify - you are using SQL Server on Linux?  Which [supported platform and version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15#supportedplatforms) are you using?  Are you in a Docker container?  Also, which [update of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-ver15#release-history) do you have installed? (what does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?)  Thanks.

Comment: [Here's how to update SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15#upgrade) if you are on an older update version.  I'm really not certain if the Brazil change made it into an update for SQL Server or not.  Let me know.  (I can follow up internally here at Microsoft if it was missed for some reason.)